# How to change just app name in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

I named my project some-name and this is bad because it is ugly. When somebody installs the app I want app name to be Some Name. How can I do it? I tried to rename it in section Identity and Type and it broke my project very bad.

I just want to say this is not duplicate. There is no answer to my question. I use cocoapods so that complicates things a bit. I didn't manage to update my app name following provided tutorial.

Comment: TS asked about product name renaming - not about project name and folders. Actually I have the same problem. I named project MCApp and I do not want to rename project but want to rename target application to the "My Cool App.app"

Answer (score 2):

You never should rename a project in Xcode without doing all the appropriate steps. Sadly, Xcode doesn't make it easy. Below is a great guide taken from here: [How do I completely rename an Xcode project (i.e. inclusive of folders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-my-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders)

This is a four step change. And is a real pain, but it works….

Step 1 - Rename the project.

1) Click on the project you want to rename in the “project navigator” on the left of the Xcode view. 2) On the right select the “file inspector” and the name of your project should be in there under “Identity and Type”, change it to the new name. 3) A drop down appears, with a “rename” ok box 4) Click rename.

Step 2 - Rename the Scheme

1) In the top bar, just by the “Stop” button, is the scheme for your OLD product, click this then “manage schemes” 2) Click on the OLD name in the scheme, and it will become editable, change the name. If you click it twice, you go into the editor (which you don’t want) click the manage schemes button to get back again.

Step 3 - Rename the folder with your assets

1) Quit out of Xcode 2) In the correctly names master folder, there is your newly named xcodeproj file with the the wrongly named OLD folder. Rename the OLD folder to your new name 3) Reopen the project and you get a warning “The folder OLD does not exist”, dismiss the warning 4) On the left in the “project navigator” click the top level OLD folder name. 5) On the right in the “file navigator” under “Identity and type” you will see the “Name” entry change this from the OLD to the new name 6) Just under this is the “location” entry, just below that is a folder symbol with the OLD name. click this and chose the newly renamed folder

Step 4 - Rename the Build plist data

1) Click on the project in the “project inspector” on the left, in the centre panel select “Build Settings” 2) in this section search for plist 3) Under packaging, you will see Info.plist, and Product bundle identifier. 4) in Info.plist rename the top entry 5) click the Product Identifier and do the same

FINALLY you are done and can rebuild (Apple-key+shift+k clean, Apple-Key+b then build)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

1. click your porject;
2. open you Utilities panel on the left side;
3. The first row shows "Identity and Type", and there is "Name" of the project;
4. change the name there, press Return, then xcode will ask you do you want to change all the target name to this name. Chosse Rename All.

Done!

Comment: That broke my project :D

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't actually have to change the name in XCode because when you will post to the appStore from Apples itunesConnect website, you will be able to place the Name Of The App in there and XCode will just be where the code is accessed!

Comment: Actually I downloaded my app from App Store to test device and the name was some-name but I typed in Some Name in app name field.