# Run custom shell script '[cp] embed pods frameworks' no such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods

Just finished resolving my errors after converting to Swift 3 only to get this error when trying to compile. I have attached a screenshot for clarity, it does not look like the system is looking for a .app file or .sh file. Really don't know too much about the Pods, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Just paste the link to your screenshot in your question, even if it's not embedded as an image it's always better than having to go to an external resource such as Google Drive.

Comment: @EricAya please see edit

Comment: Good - I have transformed it into an embedded image for you.

Comment: @EricAya Excellent, thank you!

Comment: I just started getting the same issue

Comment: @tettoffensive any idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Updated my cocoapods today and started seeing this issue.

Comment: @resin_squirrel not sure the cause, but doing a fresh install of cocoapods 1.1.1, then pod repo update, then pod install fixed it for us.

Comment: I am also facing same error ,once I update pod to my current project

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seem to have found a solution. My project name had a space in the middle of two words, very bad practice I know. Not entirely sure what caused this error, though one could possibly conclude that since the problem originated in the Pods framework, it could be related to Cocoapods, rather than migration to Swift 3.

I traced the problem to the Pods framework for my project after searching extensively for solutions to this problem.

Fixed the double quotes to single quotes on the line highlighted, and the project built instantly. Hope this helps anyone else having a similar issue!

[image]

Comment: Just to add a note - the problem is unlikely to be related to Swift 3. I had everything running fince since XCode 8 came out (I started a new Swift 3 project) - this problem started only recently. So perhaps it's the new version of Cocoapods (1.2.0.beta.1), or XCode 8.1.

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for the insight, I will add a note to clarify further that I am unsure what caused this issue, and is more likely related to the new version of Cocoapods rather than Swift 3.

Comment: @resin_quirrel Thank you for going to the trouble to paste your solution. I had the same issue and solved it as you suggested.

Comment: @skymook glad this was helpful! :)

Comment: @resin_squirrel +1 for this great solution !!

Answer (score 7):

• Just restart your system..... It Looks crazy but my problem solved.

Comment: LOL. That did it

Answer (score 0):

Swift4/5 Xcode10 Same Issue...

After upgrade cocoapods, reset pods, clean the build folder...., all these tries, it still fails... until I found this post.

However, there's no space in my project name, but do have a *special characrter* **<'>** in it. I decided to give it a try to see if it is the source of issues. After following along the instructions in [how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-projec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders), the project builds successfully, finally.

So just a **note: avoid using space or other special characters in the project name, that may cause some unexpected errors**

Answer (score 0):

add below lines in Build Phase -> [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-Swiftlly/Pods-Swiftlly-frameworks.sh
```

It is working for me