# Unable to build Archive for iOS App Release - Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode9, macos-high-sierra

```
Showing Recent Errors Only
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/sachinsr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ALL-IPO-News-ckurymjqzzhvlyaqgwdggoahngej/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ALL-IPO-News/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ALL-IPO-News.build/Release-iphoneos/ALL-IPO-News.build/Script-FD79489F910F5BA178CFE59D.sh
    cd /Volumes/Consultancy/clients/appbootup/ipo-news/all-ipo-news-ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/sachinsr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ALL-IPO-News-ckurymjqzzhvlyaqgwdggoahngej/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ALL-IPO-News/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ALL-IPO-News.build/Release-iphoneos/ALL-IPO-News.build/Script-FD79489F910F5BA178CFE59D.sh

mkdir -p /Users/sachinsr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ALL-IPO-News-ckurymjqzzhvlyaqgwdggoahngej/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ALL-IPO-News/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ALL-IPO-News.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/sachinsr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ALL-IPO-News-ckurymjqzzhvlyaqgwdggoahngej/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ALL-IPO-News/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/sachinsr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ALL-IPO-News-ckurymjqzzhvlyaqgwdggoahngej/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ALL-IPO-News/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//ALL-IPO-News.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Alamofire.framework/
Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Alamofire.framework/Info.plist

sent 7408237 bytes  received 70 bytes  14816614.00 bytes/sec
total size is 7407092  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/sachinsr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ALL-IPO-News-ckurymjqzzhvlyaqgwdggoahngej/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ALL-IPO-News/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//ALL-IPO-News.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Sachin Rajshekarappa (S3E92LENG7)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 66ACA138820D18826F0121F38CBD6C264E49B332  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/sachinsr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ALL-IPO-News-ckurymjqzzhvlyaqgwdggoahngej/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ALL-IPO-News/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//ALL-IPO-News.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/sachinsr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ALL-IPO-News-ckurymjqzzhvlyaqgwdggoahngej/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ALL-IPO-News/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//ALL-IPO-News.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have tried - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780972/xcode-9-fails-to-build-swift-4-project-with-pod

Comment: Have tried - https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Fixing-Xcode

Comment: Not Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615207/run-custom-shell-script-cp-embed-pods-frameworks-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Trying - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downcast the cocoa pods and use pod *1.3.1* install and pod *1.3.1* update .

And yes another patch on firebase upload symbol files - [Firebase Crash symbol file: Unable to upload symbol file (reason unknown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518944/firebase-crash-symbol-file-unable-to-upload-symbol-file-reason-unknown)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing derived data of the app from Xcode? And then clean,  re-build and try archiving again.

Or

Another possible situation with using Alamofire could be that you would be opening the ".xcodeproj" entry instead of the ".xcworkspace" entry. Kindly check once if any of these applies.