# When renaming Xcode project, I get "images.xcassets missing"

Tags: ios, image, xcode8

When renaming project (Xcode 8) and following the steps shown here:
[How do I completely rename an Xcode project (i.e. inclusive of folders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders), I am getting an warning saying that my images.xcassets folder is missing. 
Can anyone tell me why this might be?
I tried following steps couple of times, but it happened every time.
Is it something to do with how the folder files are grouped in the file system? I just can't work it out.

Comment: see this https://teamtreehouse.com/community/imagesxcassets-missing

Comment: There is a specific asset catalog that is not remaining after the rename. I can add a new one but then all of the loaded assets will be missing I think.