# iOS app wants to open another app after cloning it

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently cloned an iOS app I made before because it had many configurations I wanted to keep.

I cloned it and renamed it following the steps described in this stackoverflow answer : [How do I completely rename an Xcode project (i.e. inclusive of folders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders)

Everything works fine but everytime I run the app it opens a popup multiple times saying that "project2 wants to open project1" with buttons "Cancel" and "Open"

Did any of you stumbled upon the same issue ?

Thanks !

Edit:

After many researches I found out what was causing the issue.

Long story short, I use custom protocols to emit data from my webview content to my native iOS app. The thing is I used this protocol in two different apps (let's say "native-interface://" and when both were compiled on one device, both apps receive the event and both were looping on trying to open up !

I solved the issue by changing the custom protocol on one app !

Comment: Did you update the new app's bundle id?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I changed bundle id, certificate, provisionning profile too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many researches I found out what was causing the issue.

Long story short, I use custom protocols to emit data from my webview content to my native iOS app. The thing is I used this protocol in two different apps (let's say "native-interface://" and when both were compiled on one device, both apps receive the event and both were looping on trying to open up !

I solved the issue by changing the custom protocol on one app !