# Use of undeclared type 'MKMapView' even after importing MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am receiving the following error: `Use of undeclared type 'MKMapView'`.

I know this question was already asked but the answers are not the ones I'm looking for. I have already imported MapKit and UIKit.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView! // Error occurs.
```

I should note that the code runs just fine with no errors when I test it in the simulator but when I try to build it on my iPhone 6 (11.1) it gives me this error. I am using xCode 9.1 beta 1.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a collision with the actual MapKit framework because the modules have the same name. Check that your application's name is not `MapKit`.
If this didn't work try cleaning your project and building it again or restarting Xcode.

Comment: @m-tarek When you say check that my applications name is not MapKit do you mean like what I am calling the app itself as it would appear in the App Store? Because if so then it is not called MapKit. Also I already cleaned it many times with no luck as well as deleted the derived data and tried to rebuild it with the same results...

Comment: @MattMech I don't mean the display name of the app, I mean the project's name itself. It usually appears in the project navigator as your root project.

Comment: @m-tarek So do you mean the ViewController name? If so none of my Controllers have any names related to MapKit.

Comment: @MattMech Not the view controller's name, the **project's name**. You can check how to change your project's name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500038/6616757)