# Not able to delete copy of my project from Project Navigator in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I am very new to iOS development. Recently, I've downloaded one open-source project code online and enhanced it more with my own logic and code. Now, I wanted to rename it and for that, I've followed this thread for a step by step process: [How do I completely rename an Xcode project (i.e. inclusive of folders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders)

When I run the project, it was showing the missing view controllers error. So, I've updated the each view controller's path to the new updated project folder (VC's Path). Now, the errors are gone and app is working fine but I am getting 2 copies of my project in the navigator. When I am trying to delete the 2nd project, Its deleting both the projects. I don't know what's happening to it.

[Error Image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to delete only the references ?

Comment: try to delete derived data?

Comment: Yes Dixit, I've deleted the dervied data as well but its still there. @DixitAkabari

Comment: Hi Fab, I've tried to delete it with all ways, deleted only by references, deleted the derived data, even deleted the whole project and repeated the all steps again..but still not getting rid of the second project. :( @Fab

Comment: Hi @DixitAkabari... Is there any other way that you can suggest?? Please help..its very important for me..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.