# iTunes Connect - Accurate Metadata

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, info.plist

My app has been rejected a number of times from the App Store.

The guideline I have broken is:

> 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>
> We were unable to install the app on iPad and iPhone. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an iPad and iPhone.

The first time it was rejected, I realised that although I do not want my app to run on an iPad, it still needs to be able to run. So I fixed that issue and reuploaded.

The second time, I decided to just remove the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities altogether, but that still didn't work.

I'm not a hardware guy, so I don't really understand what needs to go there. It runs fine on all simulators, with or without that key.

EDIT: I asked them what devices it doesn't work on and they simply replied that they have "tried the instalment on multiple devices" and were unable to install it.

I'm very confused because I am literally testing all devices on my Mac and they all work fine?

Comment: The answer to that question is simply `remove the armv6 and armv7 keys`. In my question I said that I have `removed the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities altogether`. And I was still rejected.

Comment: You cannot remove that key. It is a "promise" to users who download from the store about which devices can run your app. This is purely a store distribution requirement, so the lack of the key-value won't have any effect in your testing, but will result in automatic rejection from iTunes Connect.

Comment: You need to put `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` back with `armv7`. However, keep in mind that Apple's rejection reasons (for smaller developers) can be duplicitous at times. i.e. the Error/issue may lie at some place completely un-related but the tester may just fail to categorize it correctly. Make sure your app looks the same in 1x and 2x in iPad as it does on an iPhone, otherwise they tend to reject it. Keep in mind, being able to run on iPad doesn't mean your App supports iPad, it simply means that user should be able to install it on an iPad. Been there and done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the answer to this issue in AskDifferent: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325464/app-review-do-they-allow-app-names-with-question-marks-in/325665#325665

Basically, **if your app has a question mark** (?) in its name and you're getting this rejection message, then **you need to remove it**.

> - Change all occurrences of your app name ( I did this: [How do I completely rename an Xcode project (i.e. inclusive of folders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders) )
> - Change the Bundle Display Name is info.plist to contain your original name (with the question mark)

Answer (score 0):

First of all according to the Apple documentation [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` must be present in your `Info.plist`. 
I would say you need at least the following capabilities:

```
armv7, arm64, location-services and gps
```

I'd suggest you try this -

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I tried with those capabilities but it was still rejected unfortunately :( I have scheduled a call with the App Review Team so hopefully I can post an answer that worked for me.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any luck with your submission?