# Can I delete the app which was rejected in iTunesConnect and upload the same code with different application name?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I've developed an app with the name "sports10", uploaded it to the iTunesConnect with the same name and got rejected due to a few issues in my project.

Now my client wants to submit the app with a different name, "cricketStar" and completely new set of UI colors (rebranding).

My question is, can I use the same developer account, to upload the rebranded app with the new name "cricketStar" after deleting the initial binary with the name "sports10" for apple's review or will they reject it without a review since the code is same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could. You would need to change the bundle id and provisioning profile for distribution.

However, you do not need to do that. You can keep the project name the same and simply change the display name in iTunesConnect->[yourapp]->App Information->name

From iTunesConnect:

> The name of your app as it will appear on the App Store. This can't be longer than 30 characters.)

And in project targets in Xcode change the display name to your desired name.

Furthermore, if you want to rename your Xcode project, here is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders) which outlines the necessary steps.

If you want to rename everything, you will need to: (1) rename the project, (2) create a new bundle id, (3) rename provisioning profiles, (4) add the new bundle id to the edited provisioning profile, (5) **create a new app in iTunesConnect**.

I would like to **stress** that doing all those steps is unnecessary. The only people that will be able to see the inconsistencies in names are the people with access to the Xcode project or iTunesConnect.

**Edit** 

From Apple:

> You can change the name of your existing app only when submitting an update of your app binary. If you submit an app name which is already in use within the same geography in which your app is sold, you will be prompted to enter another name.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to change everything related to sports10, from project name, bundleID and profile. Should I give some update during the review about the change, or is it okay to just change things and upload the new archive?

Comment: @swiftDevStart A summary of what you did would be unnecessary but won't hurt. There is no damage to be done there. I have updated my answer with a link to how to change Xcode project names.

Comment: thank you for all the details, what I'm concerned is that if I change the app display name in the project and the iTunesConnect display name like you said, and leave the bundle id and profile as it is, for an app which was already in the review cycle, rejected by apple,  now,  will they take it as a wrong move, like I'm trying to cover something up?

Comment: @swiftDevStart no they will not. It will not be rejected, assuming you fixed the issues that Apple rejected it for in the first place. You **may** change the products name.

Comment: @swiftDevStart was this helpful?

Comment: @swiftDevStart glad to hear it!