# is it needed to rename whole iOS project

Tags: ios

I have recently made an iOS app, succesfully submitted. Currently I have a similar project (same design, different values). My question is if I can use the same core, use different values, obviously I will rename the Identity and type, Bundle ID, Scheme, but the name of the workspace , info.plist will stay the same.

Comment: Why couldn't you?

Comment: But what do you mean by values when you say same design different values?

Comment: Well it's just a simple list of values (different categories, different names, different pictures, different text). Each app is of different type, but the basics stay the same

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [How do I completely rename an Xcode project (i.e. inclusive of folders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders)

Comment: Just add a new target to your existing project.