# React native project change name for ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have renamed my project using the [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) package.

It works fine on Android, however all the files in my `ios` folder still have refs to my old project name. How can I change them?

Comment: you can refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders

Answer (score 0):

Delete the IOS folder, then rebuild it again in with react-native.
I guess that's your easiest solution.