# Renaming of Xcode project merge issues

Tags: ios, xcode

I rename my project of Xcode.I got an error of library not found.I do not know what to do.Advance thanks[image: here is the image of error]

Comment: Avoid renaming your project this way, it might lead to this kind or errors, because it changes the name of the project's libraries path. Did you follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders ?

Comment: yes I follow this but I got error

Comment: Probably best to create a new project with the correct name, and then move all your source files, etc over from the old project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library path and another path in Xcode build settings seems to be hard coded instead of using `$(PROJECT_DIR)`.

You can go to XCode build settings, search for the Library Search path. You need to start the path with:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/your_library_name
```

Other Build settings you need to search are:

1. Check info.plist path
2. Header search path
3. bridging header path (if using objC and swift)