# Error message after changing Xcode project name

Tags: xcode

I am changing project name in the Xcode and am getting this error message. Anyone have idea what's wrong?

I was following steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders).

```
Code Signing /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-eupelvbeoecrkahfdrteulakjggo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/proj.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity -
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-eupelvbeoecrkahfdrteulakjggo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/proj.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/x/repos/wayd-dev-ios/proj/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-proj/Pods-proj-frameworks.sh: eval: line 123: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had an apostrophe in my packaging->produc name. I removed it and it built.

Comment: My project had the same issue. Removed the apostrophe from Display name and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what is the problem, but you should check if you have any missing quotation mark in the code, as mentioned in the error message

line 123: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Also maybe there is a reference to a file not correct. Check spelling mistakes, capital letters... and check all the steps of the mentioned post (specially Step 4 - Rename the Build plist data)