# Renaming an Xcode project for an existing AppStore app

Tags: ios, xcode, rename, identifier

I'm in the process of "rebranding" an existing app of mine, which has been on the App Store for 3 years.
This includes a new app name which should be reflected in the whole Xcode project as well.
The rebranded app should roll out as an update for all existing installations.

I've successfully followed the instructions given here:
[How do I completely rename an Xcode project (i.e. inclusive of folders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders)

(Additionally, I've changed the *bundle name* in the *info.plist*.)

with one exception: Changing the *product bundle identifier* in the *build settings*. I guess that's the only place I have to keep the old name so that AppStoreConnect realises this actually is the old app?

Is that so, if not, which is the setting that is needed to identify this as the old app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is identified using the **Bundle Identifier** only. You should not modify it. You can change almost everything else.

Note that you cannot reset the **Version** and **Build** numbers back to 1 and their values should be greater than the last numbers you used to submit your app.