# We ran “xcodebuild” command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: react-native

I am facing below issue while compiling new react native project. How to resolve this issue? Already followed below commands to resolve but not solved.

1. updated react native
2. updated npm
3. reset react-native cache
4. reset npm cache

all possible commands tried at my side.

Comment: Was there any error message output by the `xcodebuild` command? If so, please include it in the question.

Comment: @KyleWillmon:- You can see the error message like error Failed to build iOS project. We ran “xcodebuild” command but it exited with error code 65 in visual studio code while running the react native sample project. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

try to run `react-native run-ios --verbose`, that gives you an approach of what is happening, in my case, I had this error:

> the project named 'foo' does not contain a scheme named 'bar'

so I had to deal with the name and the scheme following this steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500038/1715471

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for reply.Let me check