# Trouble after renaming Xcode project

Tags: xcode

I have followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders) to change the name of my Xcode project. But after doing that, the `.xcworkspace` is empty. The `.xcodeproj` looks fine.

What can I have missed/forgot?

Comment: Do you use cocoapods in your project? If yes, you could simply delete your .workspace, Pod folder, Podfile.lock file and install pods again.

Comment: Yes! Off course! That was it. If you would like to add it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use cocoapods in your project? If yes, you could simply delete your .xcworkspace file, Pod folder, Podfile.lock file and install pods again.