# Xcode project not working after changing name of file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I messed up the project I was working from a couple of months. I was about to submit my app on the App Store, but then I changed the name of the file on my desktop and now the entire thing isn't working. now, there is a new folder in the same directory with the xcworkspace, but its all really messed up. for reference, the old name of the file was moodcal and the new name is ven. both the folders look the same in finder, but when I click on the one in moodcal, I see this, and the files cannot be opened. [moodcal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh9GH.png)
and Ven looks like this, but I cannot do anything inside
[ven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yljf4.png)
I could always make the whole project again as I have the code files, but that would take a lot of time, and I didn't use source control. 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I feel so stupid- I spent such a long time making this.

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders

Comment: well I already made the mistake, I cannot open the app anymore.

Comment: In your "moodcal" photo i can see your project, try clicking the blue file and go to file inspector and change its name. You can also try changing the name back to what it originally was and then refactor the name correctly. Also you should always use some kind of source control like git.