# Changed Project Name and Now Can't Build In Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I changed my project display name and then changed its name in the project navigator. (same new name for both). I noticed the target name didn't change. Now I'm noticing that I can't find or build the project and my intents are out of scope.

I tried changing the target name itself. It would let me click on it to edit but it wouldn't save it unless its as the old name. I also tried cleaning the build folder and restarting Xcode based on SO advice, but it didn't work.

What do I do?

Comment: did target name changed?
what is the error you're getting?

Comment: No, the target name didn’t change. I tried to change it under “targets” but it wouldn’t change.

Comment: You should try again changing name from `project navigator`. After you press return key xcode will open a popup and ask confirmation on which are the places you need to change. Select all and press return key.

Comment: Did that and it led to this.

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders or  [How to change the name of an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app) or

Answer (score 1):

On left side click `project navigator` and press enter.
[image]

rename the project and press enter, xcode will open a popup showing all references of old name. rename and its done.

[image]